# Logger log1-Slf4jLogger did not respond within Timeout(5000 milliseconds) to InitializeLogger(bus)

Tags: scala, akka, slf4j

I am running an Akka application under Akka Kernel and the program works fine in other systems.

```
akka {
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = INFO
}
```

Which is the correct slf4jLogger configuration. However when I run my application it gives the following stack trace and fails to start.

> [WARN] [01/12/2015 15:35:01.953] [main]
>   [EventStream(akka://ARCWorker)] Logger log1-Slf4jLogger did not
>   respond within Timeout(5000 milliseconds) to InitializeLogger(bus)
>   error while starting up loggers akka.ConfigurationException: Logger
>   specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger] due
>   to [akka.event.Logging$LoggerInitializationException: Logger
>   log1-Slf4jLogger did not respond with LoggerInitialized, sent instead
>   [TIMEOUT]]    at
>   akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Logging.scala:116)

There is more to the stack trace which I can paste on demand.

Has anyone seen this error and how to get rid of this?

Thanks
Manas

Answer (score 37):

You have to increase the timeout timer in your `application.conf`

```
akka.logger-startup-timeout = 30s
```

this solved the problem for me.

Comment: Struggled with this problem about an hour today. Timeout as suggested here didn't help, but reboot did (working on Arch Linux)